# How to Handle Creating Large Data Sets in R

Tags: r

There's a fair amount of support, through things like the various Revolution R modules, in what to do if you're bringing a large dataset into R, and it's too large to be stored in RAM. But is there any way to deal with data sets being *created within R* that are too big to store in RAM, beyond simply (and by hand) breaking the creation step into a series of RAM-sized chunks, writing that chunk to disk, clearing it, and continuing on?

For example, just doing a large simulation, or using something like SurvSplit() to take a single observation with a survival time from 1 to N and break it into N seperate observations?

Comment: I have found this presentation helpful: Analyzing moderately large data sets by Thomas Lumley http://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/tutorials/user-biglm.pdf

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of R? This will give you a lot more flexibility with RAM than running on a 32-bit version.

Comment: @Marcinthebox Yes - the issues are the physical *amount* of memory, not the amount addressable with 32-bit. For example, the Survsplit() example I used simply took more than 96 MB of RAM. So I cheated and ran it on a 1 TB server, but that's a crutch I may not have in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the data in R and you can do your analysis on a small chunk of the total data, then only create as large of a chunk as you need for any given analysis.